# Getting content-type for a file in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, content-type, nsfilemanager, http-post

How to get the Content-Type for any file in ObjectiveC ?

I can then set the "Content-Type" header while sending the file to any web server.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to elaborate on your question: What do you plan on using it for, among other things, might be good for answerers to know.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when using NSFileManager and friends, in fact, OS X and Objective-C in general; you should not use MIME types, but rather UTIs, or Uniform Type Identifiers. [An introduction can be found here.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html)